# How to retrieve device names on local network?

Tags: networking, wifi, arp, nmap

Currently I'm trying to retrieve the name of each device that is connected to my local network, like my phone, laptop, printer, chromecast, etc.

After doing some research, I know that its fairly simple to grab the IP address-MAC address pair of each device through an arp scan.

However, is there a way to determine the hostname of each device (e.g. Galaxy-S20), as seen when logging into the router and viewing the device list?

Note:
Running `nmap -sn <IP address>` is supposed to give you the hostname of the specified IP, however, in my case, it didn't seem to work for most devices as this command will not return the hostname if the device does not respond to ICMP.

Comment: What makes you believe it's possible? There is no protocol for discovering hostnames; it depends on how your devices is set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is there a way to determine the name of each device?`

No, not reliably. A device may not respond to anything, or only respond with minimal network information that would not include any name(s), of which there may be multiple.

Of course your business environment would not allow unknown devices, so there is most likely a repository of the information for each device on your network, such as a DHCP Server, 802.1x authentication database, various endpoint agent databases, etc. Combining these multiple sources of information is usually the most effective way to identify known and unknown devices.